# How does merging conflicts in Git compare to merging conflicts in Subversion?

Tags: git, svn, merge, conflict

When I work in Subversion, I always do an `svn update` before an `svn commit`.  If there are any conflicts, I am warned when I do the update.  Then, in my working directory, I get `filename.java`, `filename.java.mine`, `filename.java.r10`, and `filename.java.r13`.  Based on those files, I figure out how to resolve the conflict, mark it as resolved, and commit.

I'm relatively new to Git, so I'm trying to figure out what the equivalent of the above workflow is for git.  What git commands will possibly result in merge conflicts?  Are there equivalents of the above files that will show up in my working directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of `git` sub-commands that can result in merge conflicts, including `merge` (and `pull` since it's essentially `fetch` followed by `merge`), `cherry-pick`, `rebase` and others. `git` deals with merge conflicts in a fundamentally different way, though. Rather than creating individual files for the different versions, it creates a single file that has sections marked with delimiters to indicate which part of the three-way merge equation they came from. So you edit a conflicted file and either remove the sections you don't want, and the delimiters, or if neither side is exactly right, replace it with an appropriate manually-merged hybrid, then `git add` and `git commit`. The delimiters are a sequence of 7 `<`, `=`, and `>` (and sometimes `|`, if you have the `diff3` format configured) characters that look something like this:

```
<<<<<<<
stuff from your version of the file
|||||||
stuff from the common ancestor of the two
=======
stuff from the version you're merging in
>>>>>>>
```

If you're not using `diff3`-styled conflict markers, the `|` delimiters and the common ancestor lines are missing.

You can type `git help merge` to read more about it.

Comment: Cool, I didn't know about the diff3 setting.  So does this file overwrite the file in my working directory?  What happens to my uncommitted changes?

Comment: IIRC, you aren't allowed to merge when you have uncommitted changes.  You have to stash the first, then merge.

Comment: @jszakmeister That's not strictly true. If you have uncommitted changes that don't conflict with any of the merge material, it will succeed. I think conflicts with uncommitted changes will cause merge to fail though...

Comment: That seems to imply that I should either commit or stash my changes before I do `git merge`.  Is that right?

Comment: @mkasberg Unless you know for sure that the changes you've made will not conflict with the merges, either stashing or creating a temporary branch and committing there (which is pretty close to what stash does, anyway) is probably a good idea.

Comment: I've found this page to be very helpful, in addition to the answer above. http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching-Basic-Branching-and-Merging